# typescript parsing - gives error outside of conditional statement

Tags: reactjs, typescript, parsing

I'm trying to use TypeScript on React.js.

So in my class I have a function to assign state dynamically.
So here is my code :

```
onChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if (e.target.name === "username") {
            this.setState({
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value
            });
        } else if (e.target.name === "password") {
            this.setState({
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value
            });
        }
    };
```

This thing works, but when I simply write :

```
this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
```

It gives me :
[image: typescript weird parsing]

**I don't to use @ts-ignore, as I want to know, why - something goes without any error inside conditional statement, but gives error outside ?**

Here goes the interface :

```
export default interface IDefaultState {
    username : String,
    password : String,
}
```

Comment: Please, provide the state definition

Comment: Type of `e.target.name` is `string`, but type of keys state is `'username' | 'password'`. In your first case you with `if` statement help TS narrow the type `e.target.name`. In second case you can suggest TS type of `e.target.name` like `const name: 'username' | 'password' = e.target.name`

Comment: @NikitaMadeev if I had 3 state, `'username', 'password', 'phone'`, would I need 3 conditions ?

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad you can use `const name: keyof IDefaultState = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because TypeScript is telling you that your `state` object has no index signature which is a way to assign keys to an object shape.

See [TS Index Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types).

Furthermore, `e.target.name` could refer to a key that your state object doesn't have, that is, not initialised with said key. In this case `e.target.name` is inferred to be `string` inside your handler while your state object keys are `'username' | 'password'` - string literal types.

What you can do:

1. Give your state object an index signature:

   ```
   this.state = {
     username: '',
     password: '',
     phone: ''
   } as { username: string; password: string; phone: string; [k: string]: string };
   ```

But this code is very repetitive, since TS can infer the shape on object types but in order to add the index signature we must also provide all the already-present keys, so you don't lose that compile-time information.

2. More robustly, you can get the key types from `this.state`:

```
onChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        // now field is explicitly typed to be `'username' | 'password' | 'phone'`
        const field = e.target.name as keyof typeof this.state;
        if (e.target.name === "username") {
            this.setState({
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value
            });
        } else if (e.target.name === "password") {
            this.setState({
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value
            });
        }
    };
```

3. Leverage TypeScript's type inference and avoid your single handler doing too much, because you may decide to add validation to username and password fields which are quite different. I'd suggest having two separate handlers for each user input.

```
   // bind this to the username input
   // it is clear that this will only update username state
   onUserNameChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => { 
        this.setState({
           username: e.target.value
        });
    };

   // bind this to the password input
   // this is only supposed to update password state
   onPasswordChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => { 
        this.setState({
           password: e.target.value
        });
    };

   // handle phone similarly
```

This way, each handler is responsible for one thing and does it well and you don't need to add explicit type annotations on your `state` to give it an index signature. Here we are trusting TypeScript give us all the type information through inference.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statement acts as a [type guard](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/typeguard). TypeScript knows the type in the conditional block (as a literal).

To do it without that, you can do a type assertion, like this:

```
type Key = 'password' | 'username';

// ...

const key = e.target.name as Key;
this.setState({
            [key]: e.target.value
        });
```